# Is it safe to install Xampp to learn Security and Penetration testing using DVWA?

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability-assessment, dvwa, xampp

I have heard Xampp is not safe and has a lot of security loopholes. What steps need to be taken to close the loopholes? Is it better if I use a VM instead? 
I new to Security Testing and want to learn using DVWA. Kindly provide some feedback...

Comment: "Is it better if I use a VM instead?" Definitely. It is usually best practice to do assessment work/practice on a VM that you can easily restore. It's also good practice to not have this VM exposed to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to install Xampp to learn Security and Penetration testing using DVWA?

You can make it safe(r) by:

***Configure Apache and MySQL to listen only on 127.0.0.1.***

- **Apache**

  Edit the file C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and change *Listen 80* to *Listen 127.0.0.1:80*
- **MySQL**

  Edit the file C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini and make sure that the *bind-address* is set to 127.0.0.1

***Configure the firewall to block TCP port 80***

Use the Windows firewall to block incoming requests to TCP port 80.

Comment: What if used another port for xampp instead of port 80??? Will that help useful??

Comment: @Rishikesh Well in that case common sense should be used, right?

Comment: Binding only to localhost would still leave it vulnerable to cross-site requests (CSRF). An attacker can perform a request to the vulnerable applications running on localhost from his website.

Comment: @Sjoerd While this is very true, what do you consider the likelihood of this happening?